# How to make the output of command "tor" to print the last word which is "Done"?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, tor

When I run the command `tor` in cli it shows something like this:

```
May 10 22:41:08.743 [notice] Tor 0.4.5.7 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1k, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.31 as libc.
May 10 22:41:08.743 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 10 22:41:08.743 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 10 22:41:08.744 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9000
May 10 22:41:08.744 [notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050
May 10 22:41:08.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
May 10 22:41:08.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
May 10 22:41:08.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
May 10 22:41:09.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
May 10 22:41:10.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
May 10 22:41:10.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
May 10 22:41:10.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
May 10 22:41:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
May 10 22:41:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits
May 10 22:41:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits
May 10 22:41:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit
May 10 22:41:12.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done
```

Now, what I want is to only print the last word of last line which is `Done`

When I tried `tor | grep Done`, I got this:

```
May 10 22:41:12.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done
```

When I tried

- `tor | cut -d " " -f 8`
  or
- `tor | cut -d " " -s -f 8`
  or
- `tor | awk -F " " '{print $8}'`

PS: I don't understand the difference between first two, I've tried man cut. I'M A NEWBIE.
So, with the above three commands, the result was:

```
on
you
"/etc/tor/torrc".
on
connection
file
file
Starting
context
Connecting
Connected
Handshaking
Handshake
Loaded
Handshake
Establishing
Done
```

Now, when I combined "grep" and ("cut" or "awk") as shown below,

- `tor | grep Done | awk -F " " '{print $8}'`
  or
- `tor | grep Done | cut -d " " -f 8`
  or
- `tor | grep Done | cut -d " " -s -f 8`

or by writing the `grep` command after `cut` or `awk`
there is no output:

But it should have worked as I've seen on many discussion forums before asking it here.

Are my packages broken?
Or is there something fishy with `tor` command?

Comment: Is there nothing in the output, or is the output an empty line?

Comment: Likely your problem is that grep, cut and ask buffer their output when it's not to a terminal, so you're just seeing the commands wait for `tor` to fill the buffers, which isn't happening.

Comment: Read `man grep`. Use `tor | grep --line-buffered -o 'Done'`.

Comment: @muru I believe the output is an empty line as the tor command did ran; I could say that as the $ prompt didnt appeared and my cursor is just waiting for something to happen in the next line (as I pressed enter) after the execution of the command.

Comment: @waltinator DUDE, `tor | grep -o Done` also worked but yeah `--line-buffered` would be a good flag. Post them as answers, I wanna upvote you. THANK YOU :D